# Spring/JPA/Hibernate transaction management issues

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

Using:

- Spring 3.1.2
- Spring Data JPA 1.1.0.RELEASE
- Hibernate 4.1.6
- RESTEasy 2.3.5

I'm building a RESTful webservices platform talking to an Oracle database. Right now we're working on a Subscriber API. Our Subscriber repository object is mapped to a USERS table in Oracle. For versioning, we're using the ORA_ROWSCN pseudo-column on the USERS table. Here's the version member variable on the Subscriber class:

```
@Column(name = "ORA_ROWSCN", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
@Version
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
protected long version = 0;
```

When I try to execute a Create Subscriber request, I see the following in the application log:

```
Hibernate: select USERIDSEQUENCE.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into USERS (...[snip]...) values (...[snip]...)
Hibernate: select subscriber_.ORA_ROWSCN as ORA19_5_ from USERS subscriber_ where subscriber_.id=?
```

The first two lines are obviously Hibernate inserting the new USERS record; presumably the third line is Hibernate attempting to load the ORA_ROWSCN value for the new row so that it can set the version attribute on the Subscriber object. However, that results in this exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.mycompany.webservices.model.Subscriber.version;
nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.mycompany.webservices.model.Subscriber.version
```

I assume this means that the attempt to select the ORA_ROWSCN value did not return anything. Why would that be? I have a `@Transactional` wrapper around the service method that creates subscribers; I would assume that any code running in that method (or in sub-methods) can see interim database inserts/updates. But from this exception, it appears that perhaps that's not the case?

Comment: As a test, I tried changing the version member variable from a `long` to a `Long`. The create request succeeded. Then I tried an update request, which results in a `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException` when the Spring JpaTransactionManager tries to commit the transaction (the service layer update method has a `@Transactional` annotation). I think perhaps this StaleObjectStateException has the same underlying cause as the original `org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException`, which is that the code is not seeing the updated ORA_ROWSCN value resulting from the update of the USERS table.

Comment: You say you have @Transactional annotation around the service method. How are you calling the service method? From another method in the same class or from a method outside the service class?

Comment: @kabram From a method outside the service class; specifically, from a class in our Controller layer.

Comment: I've found a few online forum postings that lead me to believe that there may be a compatibility issue with Hibernate's level 2 caching and using ORA_ROWSCN as the version column, including [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2410654) and [this](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/ORA-ROWSCN-Hibernate-and-Level-2-caching).

Comment: OK, I think the problem is that Oracle does not set an ORA_ROWSCN value for a newly inserted or updated row until a commit is performed. Obviously, in this case, there is no commit until my transaction completes.